# Spring AOP: How to rethrow an exception in the async method with void return type

Tags: spring, asynchronous, spring-aop

I have the following application (the same application with Gradle + Spring Boot is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/vizr5joyhixmdca/demo.zip?dl=0):

`Writer.java` contains some code that is run asynchronously with the help of `@Async` annotation. One method returns `void` and another returns `Future`. Both variants are allowed as per documentation.

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

@Component
@Async("customExecutor")
public class Writer {

    public void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing something");
        throw new RuntimeException("Writer exception");
    }

    public Future<Void> writeFuture() {
        System.out.println("Writing something with future");
        throw new RuntimeException("Writer exception with future");
    }
}
```

`ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor.java` is a custom executor. The only difference from `ThreadPoolExecutor` is its error handling. `afterExecute` implementation is exactly the same as suggested in the method's javadoc. So the idea here is to print `"[ERROR] " + ex` when exception happens.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CancellationException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Component("customExecutor")
public class ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor() {
        super(1, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
            try {
                ((Future<?>) r).get();
            } catch (CancellationException ce) {
                t = ce;
            } catch (ExecutionException ee) {
                t = ee.getCause();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
        if (t != null) {
            handleError(t);
        }
    }

    private void handleError(Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("[ERROR] " + ex);
    }
}
```

`Config.java` enables async processing + scheduling. It also invokes `writer.write` by schedule.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class Config {

    private final Writer writer;

    public Config(Writer writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
    public void writeBySchedule() {
        writer.write();
//        writer.writeFuture();
    }
}
```

When I run this application, I see the following output:

```
Writing something
2020-07-14 21:16:33.791 ERROR 19860 --- [pool-1-thread-1] .a.i.SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler : Unexpected exception occurred invoking async method: public void com.example.demo.Writer.write()

java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception
    at com.example.demo.Writer.write(Writer.java:14) ~[main/:na]
    at com.example.demo.Writer$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$cd00988d.invoke(<generated>) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor.lambda$invoke$0(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-aop-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_242]
...
```

At the same time if I comment `writer.write()` and uncomment `writer.writeFuture()`, I get the following:

```
Writing something with future
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception with future
...
```

The latter is what I'm trying to achieve with `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor`. However I'd like to keep my methods return `void`.
I found that the reason why my exception doesn't reach custom `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor.handleError()` method is here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-aop/src/main/java/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.java#L308. This method is executed before my custom one and there seems to be no way to rethrow an exception for `void` methods. I'm aware of `AsyncConfigurerSupport` class that allows to customize exception handling, but the exception still won't escape from `AsyncExecutionAspectSupport.handleError()`.

To sum up, is there any way for my exceptions to be propagated from asynchronously executed methods to `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor.handleError()` if they declare `void` as the return type? For now it seems like I could use executors directly without `@Async`, but is it possible with `@Async`? If not, what could be the less "invasive" fix (less code to change and maintain)? I have quite a lot of async methods returning `void`.

**UPDATE**: Based on the accepted answer, I came up with the following aspect:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ErrorHandlingAspect implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    public static final String DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME = "defaultExecutor";

    private Map<String, ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor> errorHandlingExecutors;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        // initializing here because not all beans come if initialized in constructor
        this.errorHandlingExecutors = event.getApplicationContext()
                .getBeansOfType(ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor.class);
    }

    @Pointcut(
            // where @Async is on class level
            "@within(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async)"
                    // where @Async is on method level
                    + " || @annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async)")
    public void asyncMethods() {
    }

    @Around("asyncMethods()")
    public Object runWithErrorHandling(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Method method = ((MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
        Async annotation = method.getAnnotation(Async.class);
        if (annotation == null) {
            annotation = method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(Async.class);
        }
        if (annotation == null) {
            // shouldn't happen because of pointcut configuration, just for safety
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }

        String asyncExecutorName = annotation.value();
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(asyncExecutorName)) {
            asyncExecutorName = DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME;
        }

        ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor asyncExecutor = errorHandlingExecutors.get(asyncExecutorName);
        if (asyncExecutor == null) {
            // can happen if the declared executor isn't extending ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor
            // or if @Async uses the default executor which is either not registered as a bean at all
            // or not named DEFAULT_EXECUTOR_BEAN_NAME
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }

        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            asyncExecutor.handleError(throwable);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Pros:

1. Allows to handle errors in asynchronously executed code without dealing with threads.
2. Can have different error handling based on the executor.
3. Can wrap methods returning both `void` and `Future<>`.

Cons:

1. Cannot handle errors in the calling thread (only in the called one).
2. Requires to register the default executor as a bean and give it a specific name.
3. Works only with `@Async` annotations and not with async code passed directly to the executor with `submit()`.

Comment: Have you tried handling errors by AOP in an `@Around` advice instead of directly in the executor? Of course you could also combine both and only handle the `void` methods in the aspect, but you asked for something with minimal code duplication, if I am not mistaken. Maybe Spring has another, more canonical way to solve this, but I am not a Spring user, just an AOP guy. I can help with the aspect if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an aspect like this, you can get rid of your error handling block in the executor or just use a normal executor and delete the whole (not really functioning) error handling executor completely. I did and it works:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class ErrorHandlingAspect {
  // If necessary, narrow down the pointcut more here
  @Around("@within(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async)")
  public Object advice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    try {
      return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch (Throwable throwable) {
      handleError(throwable);
      // Can also return empty future here for non-void methods
      return null;
    }
  }

  private void handleError(Throwable ex) {
    System.out.println("[ERROR] " + ex);
  }
}
```

When I delete `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor`, change the annotation on `Writer` to just `@Async` and `Config.writeBySchedule` like this:

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
public void writeBySchedule() {
  writer.write();
  writer.writeFuture();
}
```

the console log looks like this:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2020-07-15 07:41:02.314  INFO 18672 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication on Xander-Ultrabook with PID 18672 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground\target\classes started by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground)
(...)
2020-07-15 07:41:06.839  INFO 18672 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
Writing something
Writing something with future
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception with future
Writing something
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception
Writing something with future
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception with future
Writing something
Writing something with future
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException: Writer exception with future
(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea with an aspect! Is it possible to use different error handling for different async methods? The reason why I put error handling to the executor is that I have multiple executors with different error handling. Seems like it is possible if I get the value of the `@Async` annotation and call the error handling method on the executor. I'll try this solution and let you know if it helps. But anyways, your solution looks promising, thanks for it!

Comment: Yes, you can. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: This worked just fine in my actual application. I posted the final code that resolved my issue in the update to the question.

Comment: The code looks a little over-engineered. Why are you still using `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor`? You said the only difference from `ThreadPoolExecutor` is error handling, but the aspect does the error handling. You should delete that class. Furthermore, I suggest to use two around advices, one for class and one for method annotation, each of them binding the annotation to a method parameter directly, so you do not need reflection to get them. Both advice methods would call another method with the common code.

Comment: > Why are you still using `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor`? -- The error handling logic depends on the executor. I have different actions for different executors. I cannot know from the method itself how exactly to handle errors. I also might have executors that don't extend `ErrorHandlingThreadPoolExecutor` and thus don't need custom error handling.

Comment: I see. Did you try my advice about refactoring? Feel free to ask if you don't understand what I mean.